# why does go yacc parser panic while defining more types?

Tags: go, yacc

I wrote a test.y file with more types. After certain limit, when I compiled the file with command,
go tool yacc test

It panics,"Index out of range in yacc.go:891"
When I looked at the file https://golang.org/src/cmd/yacc/yacc.go, I saw this comment in defining the constants
"the following are adjustable according to memory size"
Is there a reason why they have limited the number of type definition to 63(NTYPES = 63) in line 74(in the file mentioned in the link above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It panics,"Index out of range in yacc.go:891" "

I got into the same problem because I needed more types (non-term and term types) and what I did to remedy my situation was to change several values.

Please see my [GitHub page documenting my change](https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/go/commit/d4eeb860229867c76d99e67d69bdbd7cc729ce2c).

Or simply click on the URL below.

https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/go/commit/d4eeb860229867c76d99e67d69bdbd7cc729ce2c

Answer (score 1):

Interesting - I've used `go tool yacc` quite a bit and not noticed this limitation.

The reason it is like that is that `yacc.go` was ported from a C program and what you see is the obvious straight forward port.

Looking at the code of `yacc.go` it would be very straightforward to remove that limitation and turn the `typeset` array into a slice.

What I would do is [open an issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues) (check a that there isn't an existing one - I didn't see one but I didn't look very carefully). Next if you are feeling brave submit a patch using the [go contribution guidelines](http://golang.org/doc/contribute.html).  It is a good way to get into contributing to go itself.